# Is it possible to use a variable value as part of another variables name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var b = '1';
```

How can I create a variable name using the contents of variable b? I am doing this in a each loop, so b will change.

I am wanting the final product to be something like:

```
var trip1 = '';
```

How would I accomplish something like that?

```
var trip + b = '';
var trip.b = '';
```

Comment: If you're always modifying the name by adding a numeric qualifier, then perhaps what you *really* want is an Array.

Comment: @ATLChris : aggreeing to what Pointy said , use an array like
var b0=array[0] ,
var b1=array[1] ,
... and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can do it with properties of an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.b = '1'
obj['trip' + obj.b] = '';

// or

var obj = {};
var b = '1'
obj['trip' + b] = '';
```

In JavaScript, you can access properties in two ways:

1. Using a dot and a literal property name, e.g. `obj.trip1`.
2. Using brackets and a *string* property name, e.g. `obj['trip1']`.

In the latter case, the string doesn't have to be a string literal, it can be the result of any expression, hence the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing this in a each loop

Since you are iterating over them, the best way to do this is to use an array.

```
var trip = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i = 0; i < trip.length; i++){
    alert(trip[i]);
}
```

To address your question, you could store your values as properties of an object:

```
var obj = {};
var b = '1';
obj['trip' + b] = "";
```

If you are doing this in the global scope, you could also add the variable as a property of the global object:

```
var b = '1';
window['trip' + b] = "";

trip1; // == ""
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access global variables via the window object, using a dynmamic key like this:

```
var b = '1';

trip1 = 'hello';

console.log(window['trip'+b]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the eval() method.

```
var b = '1';
(eval('var trip'+b+' = 3')); // Is the same as writing var trip1 = 3;
console.log(trip1); 
//Output of variable trip1 is 3
```

Although, do a quick google search for why eval(); is bad before you employ this technique.